# How to switch off hibernate log DEBUG level?

Tags: java, hibernate, slf4j

Using hibernate 4.2.2 and slf4j 1.7.5

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And there is `org.hibernate.level=INFO` setting in logging.properties.

But I get thousands of log lines such as:

```
16:15:00,179 DEBUG [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] Loader:123 - Static select for entity...
```

How to get rid of DEBUG level log messages?

Comment: Is your logging.properties file in fact picked up? Assuming you use slf4j with plaing JDK logger, you need to add java.util.logging.config.file System property (e.g. -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties)

Comment: Check in your project any 'logback' configuration exist, if yes you need to configure in logback-*.xml